# PHP error_log() doesn't log to file specified in php.ini

Tags: php, apache, error-log

I am using php5 with apache 2 on Ubuntu.
I set the `error_log` in the php.ini to where I want php errors logged, and removed the `ErrorLog` directive from the apache virtual host configuration file.

PHP creates the file and logs to that file only when I use `error_log()` with the 3 argument version, adding the path to the log file as the third argument.
But, when I use `error_log()` with a single string argument, it logs to the apache2 default error log.

Permissions seem to be fine.
That is the only php.ini file used according to `php -i`.

Any idea what am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you using as the second parameter ?

Comment: Did you restart Apache2 after updating the configuration file ?

Comment: @MarcoBax, yes I restarted apache after updating the php.ini and the virtual host configuration file.

Comment: _“That is the only php.ini file used according to `php -i`”_ – that shows you the configuration used when PHP is run via command line – but that is not necessarily identical to the one used when you run it via the webserver. Call a script containing `phpinfo()` via the webserver, and see what configuration file is used in that situation, and what the `error_log` setting actually contains.

Answer (score 0):

@CBore - Thanks that was exactly the problem.
Once I viewed the output of `phpinfo()` from the webserver I saw it was using a different php.ini.

Thank you very much for pointing that out.